# J2me emulator not working

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm new to j2me i installed oracle j2me sdk 3.05 in netbeans...

I'm getting the error:

> C:\Users\lokesh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FirstApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:56: Classpath to J2ME Ant extension library (libs.j2me_ant_ext.classpath property) is not set. For example: location of mobility/modules/org-netbeans-mobility-antext.jar file in the IDE installation directory.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I googled a lot and i got nothing about it...

please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution...

```
Tools->Libraries->Java ME Ant Extension
```

Click on the classpath tab and re-reference the path of org-netbeans-modules-mobility-antext.jar.[ie remove the jar and add it back again]
Doing so worked for me..now itz ur turn